# How can I do a DAX naturalleftouterjoin?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I've got two tables in Power BI: *GetWordCounts* and *CountTopN*.

*GetWordCounts* has three columns: *Columns*, *Columns2*, and *Count*.

[image]

*CountTopN* has two columns: *GetWordsCount_Count* and *Count*.

[image]

I established a many-to-one relationship between the tables, linking the columns *CountTopN[GetWordsCount_Count]* and *GetWordCounts[Count]*.

[image]
(The related columns are both data typed as whole numbers.)

I created a new blank table and added: `Table = NATURALLEFTOUTERJOIN(CountTopN,GetWordCounts)`.

I receive the error: The Column with the name of 'Count' already exists in the 'Table' Table.

[image]

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. I'll appreciate any assistance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just found the answer [here](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/BUG-NATURALLEFTOUTERJOIN-can-t-be-used-to-create-calculated/td-p/38805).

Bottom line is I had columns in each of the two tables named *Count* and one of them was not part of the join condition. I renamed the one in *CountTopN* to *Count2* and the join worked.